# GetClassLoader weblogic error

Tags: java

i have any problems with weblogic 12c.

I have a java web application, it run with TomCat.

No i must trasfer this application on weblogic 12c server. I have chage any file and deploy the application. Found, but i can't read a file.jsp. (This file found correctly on TOMCAT).

I have this strcture:

Folder:

```
WebContent
- WEB-INF
  -- jsp
     --- errorIdent.jsp
```

But when i use this cose

```
InputStream in = 
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../jsp/errorIdent.jsp");
```

the inputStream object is null.

For this i try some test case and i find this file only if i put it into WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Why are you trying to read a jsp?

Answer (score 1):

`WEB-INF` is not on the classpath.

`WEB-INF/classes` is the root of the classpath.

Libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` are also put on the classpath.

Why would you want/need to read a JSP file from Java anyway?